# NoReverseMatch at is not a registered namespace

Tags: django

I see there are a lot of examples of this error, but I cannot figure out why my code is not working. I am using Django 3.0.3 and I get an error that says `NoReverseMatch at /browse/ 'browse' is not a registered namespace` in my `browse` app. It looks to me like I have everything i need, do I need to add a reference to `browse` somewhere else?

views.py:

```
from django.urls import path                              
                                                          
from . import views                                       
                                                          
urlpatterns = [                                           
        path('', views.index, name='index'),              
        path('register', views.register, name='register'),
        ]
```

urls.py:

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse              
 from django.shortcuts import render               
                                                   
 # Create your views here.                         
                                                   
 def index(request):                               
     return render(request, "browse/index.html")   
                                                   
 def register(request):                            
     return render(request, "browse/register.html")
```

layout.html:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'browse:register' %}">Register</a>
```

project-wide urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('browse/', include('browse.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove `browse` you can do directly like this

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
```

if you want to use it like

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'browse:register' %}">Register</a>
```

then you have to add `app_name = 'browse'` in urls.py

```
app_name = 'browse'
urlpatterns = [                                           
        path('', views.index, name='index'),              
        path('register', views.register, name='register'),
        ]
```